# Git Repository And Database Schemas

Tags: mysql, git, schema

My company use Git for “version control”,etc. Currently it is used for C, C# and Python. I have been asked to add the database schemas together with the more “complex” SQL (no idea when it becomes  “complex”) to the repository. Currently the database is backed up after changes have been made to the schemas or after data has been added (at the moment it is purely a development environment). Having looked at Git, database schemas and the like do not really seem (to me) to map onto it. Should I be considering another package for “source control”  to compliment the existing MySQL backups?

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are just wanting to store the SQL scripts that can recreate your DB schema without any data in it (CREATE TABLE, VIEW, INDEX, etc.) then Git seems like a perfectly good option. Git is generally good for version control of textual data, such as SQL scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The fingerprint rule is **not** to store large files which are **often modified** in git for several reasons. (out of this answer scope - heuristically, snapshots etc) so i would suggest not to add them to git directly and instead store them in a submodule as a standalone repository.

This way you can still use git to track changes but your git repository will not growth to a huge size (pack files) and you can manage it inside your project.

If you only want to store the sql script git is a good choice sine it will handle it as any other file.

Comment: The idea is to put the schemas and some SQL under source control, and definitely not the data.

Comment: So you can place it under git with no problem as a regular file, git "know" how to optimize storage. when git store the files (pack file) its optimizing the content using heuristics so when it store snapshot which is the full content of the file it actually only store the change to optimize the hard disk space but for you as user yo get it as snapshot file